# What's the meaning of "complexity" - how do I calculate it?

Tags: sonarqube, code-complexity

As the title say: I don't know the meaning of "complexity"

When I visit a web page of sonar result I would very much want to know how to calculate it.

Comment: As this is tagged with sonar, I guess "complexity" is their definition at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metrics+-+Complexity , and _not_ Big O notation for complexity.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on stackoverflow, unless you mean code-complexity which has nothing to do with sonar.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of complexity on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Complexity basically means how many actions your program performs proportional to the input. Usually it's calculated from your loops or the depth of your recursive functions.

Examples:

This has a complexity of O(n) because the actions in the for-loop are executed n times.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
```

This has a complexity of O(n^2)

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
      for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j)
```

This also has a complexity of O(n):

```
 void recursion (int level, int n) {
      if (level < n)
          recursion(level + 1, n);
 }
```

**Update:**

Reading your comment, I think you're referring to Cyclomatic complexity, you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).There's a fairly good explanation in the Description section, but to be honest, I've never used / heard of this kind of complexity.

Comment: Complexity is an asymptotical measure. It doesn't tell you  the number of action your program performs.. it tells you how many more actions it'll perform if N grows bigger.

Comment: So fast ^_^ But I'm not sure  this is the answer , In the sonar web page , it show that the commplexity data like this : 2.5/function  17.2/class 19.9/file

Comment: It tells you the number of actions performed, proportional to N. Sorry I didn't explain it adequately, but English isn't my native language.

Comment: Are you referring to the Big O notation as complexity? If you're not sure, then you probably are ;)

Comment: I find the artical: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metrics+-+Complexity ^_^